# Assigning last array element to a variable in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have this very simple line of code

```
var dblArray : [Double] = [0.01]

var x = dblArray.last

println(x * x)
```

The '.last' module returns the last element of the array, which is 0.01. However, based on the playground assistant view, it shows that the actual assignment to var x is (Some 0.01). And doing a println will lead to "Optional 0.01"

What I'm hoping to accomplish is merely capturing the value of the last element and placing it in x.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm pretty certain `.last` would have to be an optional, if only to handle the edge case of an empty array. Perhaps the playground is being smart (or dumb) about extracting the value if non-nil. In any case, if you're sure the array won't be empty, just do `dblArray.last!` (I _think_ that's the correct syntax, something with `!` anyway).

Comment: If you don't want an optional, unwrap the optional. What's the hard part here?

Comment: @paxdiablo Thank you for the answer. You have a great point about the situation if the array is empty (nil situation). So in essence, you would recommend that the only time it's best to unwrap (using !) is to check first whether the array is empty or not?

Comment: Unwrapping `nil` will cause an error. So yes, if it _can_ be empty, you should check-and-unwrap. Of course, there may be situautions where you _know_ it cannot be empty such as creating a ten-element array on program start and never removing anything. For something like that, you could blindly unwrap without issue. It just comes down to knowing all the possibilities.

Comment: @paxdiablo Excellent advice! If you post your solution as the answer, I'll select your for the answer for the community to use. Thank you again for your time and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty certain `.last` would *have* to be an optional, if only to handle the edge case of an empty array, where `.last` would make no sense as a "solid" value.

In any case, if you're sure the array won't be empty, just unwrap the value. If you're *not* sure then you'll need to check intelligently such as with:

```
var x = 0
if let junk = dblArray.last {
    x = junk
}
```

I *think* that's the correct syntax, I don't have my Mac with me at the moment, but it should hopefully be close enough to show the concept.